# Remove background and get deer as a fore ground?

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to remove background and get deer as a foreground image.

This is my source image captured by trail camera:

[image]

[image]

This is what I want to get. This output image can be a binary image or RGB.

[image]

I worked on it and try many methods to get solution but every time it failed at specific point. So please first understand what is my exact problem.

1. Image are captured by a trail camera and camera is motion detector. when deer come in front of camera it capture image.
2. Scene mode change with respect to weather changing or day and night etc. So I can't use frame difference or some thing like this.
3. Segmentation may be not work correctly because Foreground (deer) and Background have same color in many cases.

If anyone still have any ambiguity in my question then please first ask me to clear and then answer, it will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

As was commented to your question, you can detect the dear and then perform grabcut to segment it from the picture.

To detect the dear, I would couple a classifier with a sliding window approach. That would mean that you'll have a classifier that given a patch (can be a large patch) in the image, output's a score of how much that patch is similar to a dear. The sliding window approach means that you loop on the window size and then loop on the window location. For each position of the window in the image, you should apply the classifier on that window and get a score of how much that window "looks like" a dear. Once you've done that, threshold all the scores to get the "best windows", i.e. the windows that are most similar to a dear. The rational behind this is that if we a dear is present at some location in the image, the classifier will output a high score at all windows that are close/overlap with the actual dear location. We would like to merge all that locations to a single location. That can be done by applying the functions groupRectangles from OpenCV:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles

Take a look at some face detection example from OpenCV, it basically does the same (sliding window + classifier) where the classifier is a Haar cascade.

Now, I didn't mention what that "dear classifier" can be. You can use HOG+SVM (which are both included in OpenCV) or use a much powerful approach of running a deep convulutional neural network (deep CNN). Luckily, you don't need to train a deep CNN. You can use the following packages with their "off the shelf" ImageNet networks (which are very powerful and might even be able to identify a dear without further training):

Decaf- which can be used only for research purposes:
https://github.com/UCB-ICSI-Vision-Group/decaf-release/

Or Caffe - which is BSD licensed:

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/

There are other packages of which you can read about here:
http://deeplearning.net/software_links/

The most common ones are Theano, Cuda ConvNet's and OverFeat (but that's really opinion based, you should chose the best package from the list that I linked to).

The "off the shelf" ImageNet network were trained on roughly 10M images from 1000 categories. If those categories contain "dear", that you can just use them as is. If not, you can use them to extract features (as a 4096 dimensional vector in the case of Decaf) and train a classifier on positive and negative images to build a "dear classifier".

Now, once you detected the dear, meaning you have a bounding box around it, you can apply grabcut:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html

You'll need an initial scribble on the dear to perform grabcu. You can just take a horizontal line in the middle of the bounding box and hope that it will be on the dear's torso. More elaborate approaches would be to find the symmetry axis of the dear and use that as a scribble, but you would have to google, research an implement some method to extract symmetry axis from the image.

That's about it. Not straightforward, but so is the problem.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @GiLevi. I thing I need some research and study to understand all these techniques you mentioned above and then I will try to implement. Hoping it will give +ve result. Thanks again.

Comment: It is indeed a complex solution. If you want, I can guide you step by step. Mail me at gil.levi100@gmail.com and I would be happy to help.

Comment: OK Thanks a lot for your assistance. I will contact you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenCV [Background Substraction](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html) with Mixture of Gaussians models. They should be adaptable enough for your scenes. Of course, the final performance will depend on the scenario, but it is worth trying.

Comment: yes but It need background model which not available in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Since you just want to separate the background from the foreground I think you do not need to recognize the deer. You need to recognize an object in motion in the scene. You just need to separate what is static in a significant interval of time (background) from what is not static: the deer.

There are algorithms that combine multiple frames from the same scene in order to determine the background, like [THIS ONE](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins/determineSceneBackground.html).

You mentioned that the scene mode changes with respect to weather changing or day and night considering photos of different deers.

You could implement a solution when motion is detected, instead of taking a single photo, it could take a few ones with some interval of time.

This interval has to be long as to get the deer in different positions or out of the scene and at the same time short enough to not be much affected by scene variations. Perhaps you need to deal with some brightness variation, but I think it is feasible to determine the background using these frames and finally segment the deer in the "motion frame".

Comment: "There are algorithms that combine multiple frames" - Please state the algorithm or give few links for it.

Comment: First of all thank you for answering. I think you cant understand my problem, as i said may be only one or 2 images captured at a specific time and then deer come back after a hour or may be later in night then you cant use this technique.

Comment: Also remember camera is automatic and capture images automatically when motion detected. I already try averaging images and find background and then find frame difference but its not working well for my case.

Comment: Asif, what I'm trying to say is: because of theses constraints (two images in total different time) you will need to develop a very sophisticated solution. Moreover, probably this solution will be less stable and reliable and more expensive to support. In other words, perhaps you could analyze the possibility to remove these contraints and turn your problem in something more simple to solve.

Comment: Just control the camera shooting and you will have everything in hand to solve this problem in a simple way. If you cannot redefine your problem you will need to construct the background model using these images captured in different situation or really recognize an animal/deer. Good luck!